# Remove white spaces in html contents apart from using str.replace(/\s+/g, '');

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am developing a web application using codeigniter and am generating a letter content using html and javascript.What i do is that i get the html content using .html in javascript and assign it in a javascript variable and then remove white spaces using str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') and then pass the content using jquery to my controller method so that i generate a PDF file format document as a response letter and then send it to user.When i post the content to my controller function and view them in a chrome console or using mozila firebug i see the post data but when i do var_dump in the controller function the content is empty and it only happens for some cases one or two.

Is there any better way i can do it without getting these few cases...
Thanks in advance,will be grateful

Comment: _"when i do var_dump in the controller function the content is empty"_ by this it looks like you are having problems getting your php code to print posted data, so how does your title fit into this? How would using something other than `str.replace()` change that? And without some client/server code isn't much we can do to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question
I ad to replace the white spaces with a hashtag(#) from my codeigniter view as

content_with_hashtag = content_with_hashtag.replace(/\s+/g, '#');

and then pass the data to the controller function via javascript and then to the controller i had to replace the hashtag(#) with a space as
$content_with_hashtag = $this->input->get_post('content_with_hashtag');
$content_with_hashtag = preg_replace('/#+/', ' ', $content_with_hashtag);

and i was able to generate the content in PDF format